# read a value from .config file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, web-config, configuration-files, xmldom

I tried to get a value from a file with .config extension using the below code,
but i am not able to get it...........

if i change the file extesion from .config to .xml the its working fine(I am able to acheive the expected result)

```
//-----------------------------------------------------

 xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        var b = xmlDoc.load("books.config");//load a file
document.write("<br>" + xmlDoc.length);
        document.write("<br>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book").length);
        for (j = 0; j < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book").length; j++) {
            // x = xml.getElementsByTagName("FeatureToggles")[j].attributes;
            x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[j].attributes;
            y = x.getNamedItem("category");
            document.write("<br>" +"category = "+ x.getNamedItem("category").nodeValue);
            document.write("<br>" + x.length);
            if (x.getNamedItem("cover")!=null && x.getNamedItem("cover").nodeValue == "paperback") {
                document.write("Found");
            }
        }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sample xml/config:

<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Do you have to use an activeX object ? if not mandatory, a simple ajax + js will be able to parse your xml.

Comment: I am able to parse a xml but i want to parse a .config file Can you pls help in tht

Comment: As of the load function, i suppose your server return your the file, can you try to call manually http://yourserver/books.config and http://yourserver/books.xml . If the former fail, it most probably because your webserver isn't configured to return .config files

Comment: Actually i m trying to do this in local machine as of now no servers are used i am using this script in a html file to get a value from a custom(external) config file

Comment: try tht code by changing the file extension from books.xml to books.config

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because the `load` method requires an XML file and your browser doesn't know that the .config extension is actually XML. If you were serving this file from a server, you could add the proper headers to tell the browser that the .config file is XML. Without the headers, your browser has to try and figure it out (this process is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If this hypothesis is correct, the variable `b` that you are setting in your question (the return value of the load method) should be false.

> xmlSource: A string containing a URL that specifies the location of the
>   XML file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To fix this, you can serve the file with the proper headers (the best approach if this is an app others will use), tell your browser to handle .config files as XML (probably not a good idea) or just use the .xml extension since this seems to be mapped by the browser automatically.

Comment: actual xml/config used is having xml headers,(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>)

Comment: what i have to do read the config file using simple javascript

Comment: Looks like there is a good example on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML - see the section under "Using XMLHttpRequest"

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in the browser by default will not load arbitrary files from the filesystem.

In order to achieve what you want:

1. Disable cors security in your browser
2. Start a small server in the directory serving index.html and config

This process is outlined [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx).

**note:** revert your browser settings after you're finished as you're effectively disabling important security measures.

**update:** I didn't read your question thoroughly, and the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) mention that a local XML works.

Comment: I tried XMLHttpRequest earlier itself but its not helping in this scenario